# How to make textbox readOnly

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

How do I make this a readOnly textBox, and the text inside it appear as gray?

```
<%=  Html.TextBox("name")%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have an initial value you can as well provide only attributes anonymous object with relevant attribute set as

```
<%=  Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @readonly = true })%>
<!-- or -->
<%=  Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

If you do have a value to set to this text box these two should be

```
<%=  Html.TextBox("name", "Some textbox value", new { @readonly = true })%>
<!-- or -->
<%=  Html.TextBox("name", "Some textbox value", new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

The thing is that such attributes as `readonly` or `hidden` should be set without any value (according to specification), but you can't provide such attributes using standard `Html` helper methods. The good thing though is that you can set anything as a value. But for the sake of readability and making them meaningful it's best to set them either to `true` or attribute name as shown in my example.

Comment: <%=  Html.TextBox("parent", null, new { @readonly = true })%>

Comment: How to add text to that textbox?

Comment: @Shaza: Do you mean textbox value? Check my edited answer if you answered as *yes, I mean value*.